# MATLAB urlread from live timing website

Tags: matlab, urlread

this is a website with a live timing table:

http://www.apex-timing.com/live-timing/lemans-karting/index.html

Do you guys know whether the Matlab function urlread lets me read this kind of data?

Using

str = urlread('http://www.apex-timing.com/live-timing/lemans-karting/index.html')

returns a single string with lot of info probably related to the website code but nothing related to what I see on the website.

Cheers,

Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website dynamically creates/updates its content using JavaScript. So I think that there is no easy way to read the data you want using Matlab. You would have to look at the script ( http://www.apex-timing.com/live-timing/common/Scripts/jquery-go.js ), unpack it and try to figure out how it works, however this is likely to be difficult and might violate the terms of service of the website.

Comment: Thanks for your answer magnetometer. I'm thinking about a workaround: suppose I open the url within the matlab browser (wb=com.mathworks.mde.webbrowser.WebBrowser.createBrowser), so I can wait the javascript to connect to the server and show me the times table, as soon as I have all the times within the matlab browser, is there any way to get that HTML data using the wb java component?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the WebBrowser component. You can get a list of the methods with ``wb.components`` . ``wb.getHtmlText`` looked promising for me, but I only got the unchanged contents of the original webpage. However, there might be other methods that are more helpful. Sadly, there doesn't seem to be official documentation on that topic.

Comment: Thanks magnetometer. I've found the solution in using the WebBrowser component and it's wb.getHtmlText method. I was behind a proxy and this didn't let me to use the getHtmlText properly but I then realized that the method works fine without a proxy. Hope this helps others.